# how to pdfjoin landscape and portrait oriented JPEG images to one PDF file?

Tags: pdf, conversion, jpeg, join

I have some JPEG files. Most of them are landscape oriented, but some are portrait oriented.

I want to combine them into one big PDF file. I tried `pdfjoin` but this results in all images beeing landscape oriented.

Strange thing is: When I do the joining only on the portrait oriented images, then all images are portrait oriented. Same with all images that are landscape oriented. But if I do `pdfjoin` on all images at a time, then the result is always landscape oriented, which means, that if you watch the PDF file you have to turn your head by 90 degrees to watch the images that were portrait oriented originally.

I would like to have an easy command line solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

Oh, I just found a solution. I used [GraphicsMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/) to achieve it. So `pdfjoin` wasn't a good choice.

This is my solution:

```
gm convert *jpeg output.pdf
```

Still I ask myself if there is a solution with pdfjoin or similar. Just curious.

Comment: Cool. I've never heard of this project, it's a forked version of ImageMagick, project looks good, and the project looks pretty active and thriving. Incidentally you can do the same using the ImageMagick tool, `convert`.